# C++/CLI Convert Bitmap to OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, c++-cli

I'm trying to develop a small C++/CLI wrapper around OpenCV for use in a C# application. *I can't use Emgu since it's for a commercial application.*

I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to convert from `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to `OpenCV Mat`.

I have the following code:

```
cv::Mat BitmapToMat(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bitmap)
{
    System::Drawing::Rectangle blank = System::Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap->Width, bitmap->Height);
    System::Drawing::Imaging::BitmapData^ bmpdata = bitmap->LockBits(blank, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb);
    cv::Mat cv_img(cv::Size(bitmap->Width, bitmap->Height), CV_8UC3, bmpdata->Scan0.ToPointer(), cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
    bitmap->UnlockBits(bmpdata);

    return cv_img;
}
```

I'm using it in cpp file to test out the generated Mat like this:

```
Mat image = BitmapToMat(templateImage);
cv::imwrite("some2.jpg", image);
```

But the image produced is completely distorted (see images)

**INPUT BITMAP IMAGE**

[image: ORIGINAL IMAGE]

**RESULT MAT IMAGE SAVED TO FILE**

[image: RESULT IMAGE]

Comment: Can you get your bitmap "step" to replace cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP ?

Comment: @Ziri I removed that and checked, still no difference

Comment: What about OpenCVSharp? That one's BSD licensed as opposed to the apparently GPLd Emgu.

Comment: What's the stride of the BitmapData? If I'm not mistaken, windows bitmaps ten to have the rows aligned on multiples of 4. Hence `step` should be set to the stride, otherwise (when image width is not a multiple of 4 as is the case here) you don't skip the padding and the following rows get each shifted right by a few pixels -- quite evident from your second image.

Comment: @DanMašek Can I set `int wb = bmpdata.Stride` directly? The accepted answer calculated the step mannually, which confuses me.

Comment: For my last comment: maybe abs(bmpdata.Stride)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows bitmaps are padded. You want to calculate "width in bytes" of the bitmap row, and supply that instead of `cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP`:

```
int wb = ((bitmap->Width * 24 + 31) / 32) * 4;
cv::Mat cv_img(cv::Size(bitmap->Width, bitmap->Height), 
    CV_8UC3, bmpdata->Scan0.ToPointer(), wb);
```

Comment: Can I set `int wb = bmpdata.Stride` directly? What's the point of calculating the step ourselves?

Comment: Maybe abs(bmpdata.Stride)?

Comment: @Tomingsun I was not aware of `Stride`, you can use it if it's available, it should be the same value as `wb` above